# Jquery: submit the closest form

Tags: jquery

I am trying to submit the closest form because there are somany forms in the same id and name

```
<form id="frmid" method="post">
// so many tags here
<button  onclick="setTimeout(function(){ updatecartshi(this)()}, 1000);">+</button>
// so many tags here
</form>
```

and the function is

```
function updatecartshi(obj)(){
   $(obj).closest("#frmCart").submit();
}
```

but this is not working my my form is not submitted

Thanks in advance

Comment: `there are somany forms in the same id and name`. That's your problem. Fix the `somany forms in the same id and name` and it works.

Comment: Elements cannot have same Id. There is a reason why it is called ID. Gve them classes

Comment: is there any way to submit the form which contains the button

Comment: Inside `setTimeout()` callback, `this` refers to window... Now bind instead `submit` event of form using unobstrusive javascript. Your button already submit the `form`

Comment: @A. Wolff I am new to jquery could you please explain it or post it as answer

Comment: No because regarding your posted code, the form would be submited but you said it isn't. So i won't try to guess whatelse you are doing wrong. Post minimalistic sample replicating your issue...  And your code try to submit `#frmCart` form, but there is no form with that ID in your code. So what are you trying to do? Submit other form or what???

Answer (score 0):

You need to set different `id` for each form. ID is a unique key for each element and can't same with other element id.

If you want to do like that, use `class`.

`<form class="frmid" method="post">`

Class name can be same for different element.

Answer (score 0):

For the friends who wants to know the answer for this question

```
  onclick="var obj=this;setTimeout(function(){ $(obj).closest('#frmCart').submit();}, 1000);"
```